# Angular2 secure access to files

Tags: angular

How to access json files in asset folder. There are some json files which are used by components. Now we dont want these files to be directly accessed in the url. What is the correct way to access which contain confidential data.

Comment: Generally assets folder is not confidential but public folder. So it is accessible by anyone. If you want a json to be confidential then create a rest api and then request the json data from the authenticated rest api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access it in a secure way then first remove it from public folder because it will directly accessible by url.
The best way is to create a api on server and get a json object or If you want as json file then get in body as stream and use blob to store on client machine.

Hope it will help